# Everytime the seed job runs all the parameterized jobs generated through it are defaulting to 'build now' instead of 'build with parameters'

Tags: jenkins, groovy, job-dsl

**Context**:
I have a seed job using the plugin Jenkins Job DSL. It is checking out a repository in git and generating a jenkins job for each .groovy file by reading all the .groovy files in the repository.
**Problem**:
When I make a change to existing job's groovy or add a new job's groovy file and run the seed job, then all the existing parameterized jobs are switching from "build with parameters" option to "build now" as if this is a new build and needs to run once in order to read the Jenkins file. I have over 100 parameterized jobs that are being generated through this seed.
**Acceptance criteria**:
I need to keep the existing jobs unaffected when the seed job runs. Only the job's groovy files that are modified or newly added should get effected.
Any leads would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9V42.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9V42.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69113557/jenkins-build-with-parameters-button-keeps-disappearing 2found this answer, check this if it helps.